# How to enable/disable option menu item on action bar based on server response in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to enable/disable option menu item on action bar based on server response in Android. I can disable the options menu using this code

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    if (isFinalized) {
        menu.getItem(1).setEnabled(false);
    }
    return true;
}
```

But my need is, I want to disable the menu item with server response key

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store `Menu` object in your `Activity` or `Fragment` whichever you use.

```
private Menu mMenu;
```

and

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    mMenu = menu;
}
```

in your server response class (e.g. `AsyncTask` or `Volley` etc..), after the response access that `mMenu` object and update it.

```
 menu.getItem(id).setVisible(false);    // do whatever operation you want 
 invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Answer (score 2):

> Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    mMenu = menu;
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_invitation_detail, menu);
    if (isFinalized) {
        menu.getItem(0).setVisible(false);        
    } else {
        menu.getItem(0).setVisible(true);          
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```